# PropertyNotFoundException occurs even when the getter is present

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets

I am working on a small messaging web application to learn jsp's and servlets. I have a MessageModel class with the following properties :

```
String toAddress ;
String fromAddress;
String messageSubject;
String messageContent;
Timestamp messageTime;
int messageDraft;
```

And their corresponding setters for a jsp to access.

I have a method which queries a database with all the messages for the messages received to a particular address to display. It then creates a new `MessageModel` object and stores it in a ArrayList.

```
public static ArrayList<MessageModel> getReceivedMessages(String toAddress) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
    // creates a arraylist.
    ArrayList<MessageModel> msgList = new ArrayList<MessageModel>();

    // Database connection code..

    // The query which gets the required messages from the database and adds them to the list.
    String query = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE msg_to='" + toAddress +"' ORDER BY msg_date DESC";
    Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
    if(rs.next()){
        while(rs.next()){
            String msgTo = rs.getString("msg_to");
            String msgFrom = rs.getString("msg_from");
            String msgSub = rs.getString("msg_subject");
            String msgCnt = rs.getString("msg_matter");
            Timestamp msgTime = rs.getTimestamp("msg_date");

            MessageModel model = new MessageModel(msgTo,msgFrom,msgSub,msgCnt,msgTime);
            msgList.add(model);
        }
    }
    return msgList;
}
```

I call this method from the jsp and save the list as an attribute by using

```
 String userName = (String) session.getAttribute("userId");
 ArrayList<MessageModel> list = MessageModel.getReceivedMessages(userName);
 pageContext.setAttribute("messageList", list);
```

But when I access the fromAddress property of the MesasgeModel objects in the list through a `<c:forEach>` tag, I get the following error :

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'fromAddress' not found on type com.email.system.MessageModel
```

This is the part of the HTML which access prints out the contents of each `MessageModel` object.

```
<c:forEach items="${messageList}" var="message">
  <li><c:out value="${message.toAddress}"/>
      <c:out value="${message.messageSubject}"/> <c:out value="${message.messageTime}"/>
      <c:out value="${message.messageContent}"/> <c:out value="${message.fromAddress}"/> </li>
</c:forEach>
```

The error occurs whenever I try to access the `toAddress` field. The toAddress property is being stored int the `messageSubject` field even though when I try the same query in the mySql console I get the proper fields in their respective columns.

An exapmle result to the query where I removed the content column,

```
msg_id  msg_to  msg_from  msg_subject  msg_date             msg_is_draft
4       bigb    remember  *subject*     2014-10-07 11:01:53  0
2       bigb    remember  *subject*     2014-10-07 10:48:43  0
1       bigb    remember  *subject*     2014-10-07 10:48:31  0
```

EDIT: This is the `MessageModel` class I have.

```
public class MessageModel {
    String toAddress ;
    String fromAddress;
    String messageSubject;
    String messageContent;
    Timestamp messageTime;
    int messageDraft;

    public String getToAddress() {
        return toAddress;
    }

    public String getFromAddress() {
        return fromAddress;
    }

    public String getMessageSubject() {
        return messageSubject;
    }

    public String getMessageContent() {
        return messageContent;
    }


    public Timestamp getMessageTime() {
        return messageTime;
    }

    public int getMessageDraft() {
        return messageDraft;
    }

    public MessageModel(String toAddress,String fromAddress, String messageSubject, String messageContent,Timestamp messageTime){
        this.toAddress = toAddress;
        this.messageSubject = messageSubject;
        this.messageContent = messageContent;
        this.messageTime = messageTime;
        this.fromAddress = fromAddress;
    }

    public void sendMessage(MessageModel model){
        //Gets the related properties from the objects and stores it in the database
    }
    public static ArrayList<MessageModel> getReceivedMessages(String toAddress){
        //Gets the messages sent to 'toAddress'
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your `MessageModel` class. The properties are derived from the getter/setters not from the name of field. So you should have a `getToAddress()` method for a `toAddress` property.

Comment: I use intelliJ, I used the code insertion tool to create the setters for the class. I understood how a jsp requires these as per the JavaBeans specification from another SO question.

Comment: As always with these kind of problems, try a full clean, rebuild, redploy.

Comment: I was typing out a reply to your comment saying how I always just update classes and resources since I don't use any build tools, but midway through it I redeployed just for the heck of it and what do you know, it works! I had been slaving away with this problem for about an hour now with no results. How the hell does this even work..

Comment: It's annoying isn't it? You should probably delete this question. Alternatively I could post an answer of this for you to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out if you make some changes to any java source file which you use in you application you have to do a full rebuild and redeploy for the changes to take place.

There wasn't anything wrong in my code when I asked my question, instead of redeploying I was just updating resources. That only updates changes made to the JSP's not the java sources.